# How can I start debugging R or Python code using the same key in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Trying to avoid the XY problem, my problem at the very high level: I work in a VS Code workspace with R and Python code files, and I often need to debug one or the other. Currently I have different debug launch configurations saved, and I need to switch between them manually - that is a pain. I would like to use F5 to

- launch the Python debugger when the editor is active in a `.py` file
- launch the R debugger when the editor is active in a `.R` file

I see many technical ways of doing that, but all have their roadblocks (some of which may just poor documentation):

1. Create my own extension with a dynamic debug configuration that determines the type of the active editor and starts the correct debug configuration. (A lot of effort required.)
2. Use a `"compound"` launch configuration, starting both R and Python launch configurations, and stopping all but one. This can be done using a `"prelaunchTask"` for each, but non-zero return codes create error message that I don't like.
3. Use editor-dependent key mappings (`"when": "editorLangId == 'python'"`), but which command for debugging to start and how to pass the launch configuration? There is `vscode.startDebug` which takes arguments (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/4615), but I cannot keybind to that. And then there is `workbench.action.debug.start` which seems to ignore arguments. And then there is `vscode.commands.executeCommand` to which I cannot keybind, either.
4. Use a multi-command extension to bind a key to something like "set debug configuration, then press F5". But how to do that?
   Etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

After much fiddling, here is one solution following idea 2:

`settings.json` (launch configs could be put into `launch.json`):

```json
{
    "debug.onTaskErrors": "abort",
    "launch": {
        "compounds": [
            {
                "name": "Python/R: Current File",
                "configurations": [
                    "Python: Current File",
                    "R: Current File",
                ],
            },
        ],
        "configurations": [
            {
                "name": "Python: Current File",
                "type": "python",
                "preLaunchTask": "check_ext py",
                "request": "launch",
                // ...
            },
            {
                "name": "R: Current File",
                "type": "R-Debugger",
                "preLaunchTask": "check_ext R",
                "request": "launch",
                // ...
            }
        ],
    },
}
```

`tasks.json`:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "check_ext py",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "echo ${fileExtname} | grep -i ^.py$",
        },
        {
            "label": "check_ext R",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "echo ${fileExtname} | grep -i '^.R$'",
        },
    ],
}
```